Models did break after trying to animate mech


After clicking on animation tab to try animate my mech , all part did break .
i linked all part togheter with the origine at center of all round piece . But i think this isnt how you rig a mech , is it.every object transform broke.And if i load old save everthing still broken QQ

Is there a reason why you don't use an armature for animation? If you keyframe the cube's location directly (screenshot 2) then it's absolute. You won't be able to move it as a whole, rotate it, or use the animation for another object. Furthermore, the Scale is not applied and is non-uniform (different values for X, Y, and Z). This will cause problems. The Scale and Rotation should be applied before you do any animation.

ty for your awnser, but how do i clean this mess . All my save are "corupted" How to remove all data related to animation so i can retry

i found how  ty https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMUgfh0mAxM
